# Tried implementing Gradient Descent

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am totally new to ML and python, Read linear regression and tried to implement gradient descent

first, Could anyone please let me know what wrong I am doing?

Input Data  -

```
    x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
    y = (2*x + 5) + np.random.normal(0, 1, len(x))
    curve = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([x,y]), columns = ['x', 'y'])
```

Gradient Descent Code -

```
    learningRate = 0.1
    m = 0
    c = 0
    n = len(x)
    j = [0]*300
    j[1] = sum((curve.y - (m*curve.x + c))**2)/n
    iter = 1
    err = 1
    while(err > 10**-3):
        Dc = (m*curve.x +c) - curve.y
        Dm = ((m*curve.x + c) - curve.y)*curve.x
        m = m - 0.1 * sum(Dm)/n
        c = c - 0.1 * sum(Dc)/n
        iter = iter +1
        j[iter] = sum((curve.y - (m*curve.x + c))**2)/n
        err = abs(j[iter] - j[iter -1])
        print('error :',err)
    print('iter : ', iter)
    print('m : ', m)
    print('c : ', c)
```

It give me correct result as below error terms goes on decreasing and it comes up with estimated 
    vales of m and c:

```
error : 97.29992615029744
error : 34.92089545773186
error : 12.579806110060302
error : 4.5766394765497145
error : 1.7080644275745156
error : 0.6783105614574572
error : 0.307139765746657
error : 0.17189857726871516
error : 0.12122915945728607
error : 0.10092634553882229
error : 0.09157601971420037
error : 0.08622305155313681
error : 0.08237404842923546
error : 0.07913349054978847
error : 0.07617816054863757
error : 0.07338987727769242
error : 0.07072397231883842
error : 0.06816218746680436
error : 0.06569580397224817
error : 0.0633195980665846
error : 0.061029673548781194
error : 0.0588226828738998
error : 0.0566955455716478
error : 0.05464534485749262
error : 0.05266928814789651
error : 0.05076469054898958
error : 0.04892896665787916
error : 0.04715962542349139
error : 0.04545426618265713
error : 0.043810575193886425
error : 0.042226322423362106
error : 0.04069935849262318
error : 0.0392276117528354
error : 0.037809085470765336
error : 0.03644185511853815
error : 0.03512406576218341
error : 0.033853929544860106
error : 0.032629723261214494
error : 0.03144978601945159
error : 0.030312516988004745
error : 0.029216373223642567
error : 0.028159867578168907
error : 0.02714156668077994
error : 0.026160088993397057
error : 0.025214102936330196
error : 0.02430232508170649
error : 0.023423518412224897
error : 0.022576490642901792
error : 0.021760092603465342
error : 0.020973216679284867
error : 0.020214795308643785
error : 0.019483799534385726
error : 0.0187792376078999
error : 0.01810015364362627
error : 0.017445626322180052
error : 0.016814767640402017
error : 0.016206721706588878
error : 0.015620663579299254
error : 0.01505579814815139
error : 0.014511359055082274
error : 0.013986607654631555
error : 0.013480832011810495
error : 0.012993345936206158
error : 0.012523488051036091
error : 0.012070620895839435
error : 0.011634130061635828
error : 0.011213423357342878
error : 0.01080793000635838
error : 0.010417099872163771
error : 0.01004040271197626
error : 0.009677327457328522
error : 0.009327381520729094
error : 0.008990090127349415
error : 0.008664995670889075
error : 0.008351657092750653
error : 0.008049649283635052
error : 0.007758562506807065
error : 0.007478001842195603
error : 0.007207586650595843
error : 0.006946950057259871
error : 0.00669573845415905
error : 0.006453611020228234
error : 0.006220239258977411
error : 0.005995306552818436
error : 0.005778507733510185
error : 0.005569548668120872
error : 0.005368145859991458
error : 0.005174026064101778
error : 0.004986925916362628
error : 0.004806591576302477
error : 0.004632778382688496
error : 0.004465250521578756
error : 0.004303780706404803
error : 0.0041481498695978836
error : 0.003998146865395347
error : 0.00385356818335314
error : 0.003714217672262876
error : 0.0035799062740193843
error : 0.0034504517671292145
error : 0.0033256785194886174
error : 0.0032054172500981526
error : 0.0030895047994004
error : 0.002977783907922804
error : 0.002870103002917457
error : 0.0027663159927209247
error : 0.0026662820685543487
error : 0.002569865513485592
error : 0.002476935518296086
error : 0.002387366004018787
error : 0.0023010354508823383
error : 0.002217826733440287
error : 0.0021376269616657506
error : 0.002060327327805034
error : 0.0019858229587441656
error : 0.0019140127737211632
error : 0.0018447993472126
error : 0.0017780887767346876
error : 0.0017137905554454047
error : 0.0016518174493684867
error : 0.0015920853790276634
error : 0.0015345133053750182
error : 0.0014790231198629211
error : 0.0014255395384494829
error : 0.0013739899994744675
error : 0.0013243045652084895
error : 0.0012764158269753523
error : 0.0012302588136838821
error : 0.0011857709036990904
error : 0.001142891739868812
error : 0.0011015631476423149
error : 0.0010617290561396597
error : 0.0010233354220909874
error : 0.0009863301565038451
iter :  134
m :  2.0833620160267663
c :  4.610637626188058
```

But when I take input as (just increased one element in my array)

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
y = (2*x + 5) + np.random.normal(0, 1, len(x))
curve = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([x,y]), columns = ['x', 'y'])
```

Result comes like :(why my error keeps on increasing in this case)

```
error : 29.09815015431613
error : 34.01872638453614
error : 39.76520568567241
error : 46.47644714481737
error : 54.31464731003979
error : 63.46926275846772
error : 74.16159195797525
error : 86.65012723507334
error : 101.23680628672548
error : 118.27431442939576
error : 138.17461419084918
error : 161.41890853364032
error : 188.56927867181366
error : 220.28227794256668
error : 257.32481050201727
error : 300.5926788730269
error : 351.13224891948175
error : 410.16575621676475
error : 479.12086585577663
```

Please let me know what wrong I am doing?

Tried implementing Gradient Descent, but if I take longer input vector means more examples then I m error terms keeps on increasing instead of decreasing

Comment: Please beware of your formatting and definitely **proofread** after posting to ensure that everything reads as intended; you actual question (and many more stuff) were actually buried inside your code snippets (edited). Also, in similar questions, you should include the respective language tag (added). Finally, "cute" stuff like the one included at the end should not be posted here - questions are supposed to be concise and to the point (removed).

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately I am new to stack overflow too. I will take care of formatting next time.

Comment: I would standardize the data. What I mean is subtract the means from `x` and `y` and divide by their standard deviations. It will lead to faster, consistent convergence no matter what data you're using. You'll need less iterations and you can play with a larger learning rate. You will then need to unstandardize the data and coefficients which can be done with some simple algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here.
First of all you defined the learning rate but didn't use it

```
    m = m - learningRate * sum(Dm)/n
    c = c - learningRate* sum(Dc)/n
```

Secondly your learning rate is to large. Choose a value like 0.01

If you change your print statement to 
    print('error : {} m: {} c: {}'.format(err,m,c))

you can see the learned parameters are oscillating

```
error : 4.627422172738745 m: 6.2021421523611355 c: 1.3127611648190132
error : 5.407226002504083 m: -0.5251044659276074 c: 0.013389352211670591
error : 6.318019832044391 m: 6.721890877404075 c: 1.53485336818056
```

Comment: Do you want to say that by choosing the learningRate as 0.1 I have crossed minimum of the function every time in the iteration and it keeps on oscillating like you identified. Am I right?

Comment: @RahulKumar Indeed. I'm a bit surprised because you normalise by the number of training examples. You could have look in more advance algorithms like adagrad